# Streaming Video in Parts

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a question about how I can stream a large video in parts. Lets say I have a video that is 1G large and I want to break into 10 equal parts (~100MB each). Now what I want to do is have a video player (preferably HTML5 /JS and not a Flash Player) that plays these 10 videos from start to finish without any noticeable gaps in-between.

The purpose of this is to to make sure that the entire video is NOT being downloaded in cases when user isn't watching the entire video.

Is this a pointless exercise?
Do you actually save bandwidth by considering this implementation?
Are there solutions like this already?

Thank you!

Comment: There are solutions like this -- well-tested, industry-standard solutions being used by all the biggest players in the industry (YouTube, Netflix, etc.). Look at HLS and MPEG-Dash, both of which break video into much smaller segments than you're imagining. Both solutions have multiple HTML5 implementations. And yes, you can save a great deal of bandwidth this way.

Comment: Thanks jlmcdonald, this is really helpful. Are there server side implementations of HLS or MPEG-Dash already, for example in Apache? I guess what I'm trying to find out is whether there are client side as well as server side solutions that break your videos in segments without you having to do this manually.

Comment: Both HLS and MPEG-Dash are designed to work with files served over regular HTTP, so there isn't a streaming server requirement at all. But in terms of your question about segmenting, you could choose to either A) user a streaming server that segments on the fly (like Wowza), or B) pre-segment everything, with a tool like ffmpeg, Apple's mediasegmenter, etc. See this link to help you get in the right direction: http://hlsbook.net/segmenting-video-with-ffmpeg/

Comment: Thanks ljmcdonald. I have seen a video before stating that with dash it is no longer necessary to segment files, but I can't find how such thing would be implemented (perhaps not possible yet). I have been able to segment files using ffmpeg but I was wondering if there is a library or module that handles this automatically like wowza. I am assuming that I will need to write my own?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, the described way of consuming videos is called adaptive streaming. There are several similar technologies in this context available, like MPEG-DASH, HLS, Smooth Streaming,... Where one can see a shift towards MPEG-DASH within the video streaming industry - platforms like Youtube and Netflix are using DASH for instance.

You can find several different vendors for encoding as well as players, like [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/), [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/?), and many more. A good starting point to get familiar with adaptive streaming can be found [here](https://bitmovin.com/ultra-high-definition-quality-experience-mpeg-dash-part-1/) and [here](http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/What-Is-.../What-is-MPEG-DASH-79041.aspx).