# How to split the videos into multiple packets using php?

Tags: php, video-streaming, html5-video, html2canvas

I Just want to buffer a video manually, so I need to split the videos into smaller packets.
For example: convert 6 MB video into 6 - 1 MB small videos.

Is this feasible using PHP?

Comment: you can't do this using php alone. you should check ffmpeg and https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg for this

Comment: Thanks Vigikaran, Any sample i can get to understand FFMpeg easily? or any example in online

Comment: https://github.com/olaferlandsen/ffmpeg-php-class this may be usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds related to the [questions about "Streaming Video in Parts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543701/streaming-video-in-parts/35727506#35727506).

As mentioned, the described way of consuming videos is similar to adaptive streaming. An introduction to that topic can be found [here](http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/What-Is-.../What-is-MPEG-DASH-79041.aspx).

If you are bound to PHP, you can still use it to generate segmented content, with Bitmovin's API, as shown in the example at https://github.com/bitmovin/bitcodin-php.